# intuitive explanation of Doleans exponential of Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus

A simple SDE is given as: $$dX_t=\sigma X_tdW_t$$
Ito's lemma confirms that the following is a solution:
$$X_t=X_0e^{\sigma W_t-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2t}$$

I understand how this result is correct according to Ito's lemma, but I don't see why it makes any sense that the $-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2t$ is there.

For example: Assume that a very unlikely thing happens, namely $W_t=0$ on some interval $t\in[0,a]$. I know that this will Almost Surely not happen, but assume it nontheless (I think the same conclusion should apply if $W_t$ simply coincidentally stays very very close to $0$).

**Then we have a situation where $dW_t = 0$ over this interval, and therefore $dX_t=\sigma X_t*0=0$ over this interval. Hence $X_t$ should remain constant over this interval.**

Nevertheless, we have $X_a=X_0e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 * a}<X_0$, so that $X_t$ does **not** remain constant on the interval.

If we let go of the assumption that $W_t$ is exactly equal to $0$, but assume that it fluctuates extremely closely around $0$ for a relatively large amount of time, then we still get the seemingly incorrect result that $X_t$ drops to zero over time.

**How do we explain this?**

---

Let me formulate my question in less technical terms: **If the change of $X$ depends only on the change of the brownian motion $W$, then why does $X$ go to zero over time according to a factor $e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2}$, regardless of how the Brownian motion moves?** i.e. regardless of how close the Brownian motion remains to zero, $X$ still moves exponentially fast towards zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ito's formula in differential form is $$df(t,x) = f_t dt + f_x dW + \frac{1}{2} f_{xx} dt$$,
let's consider a simple situation that $f=f(x)$, denote $g:=f_x$, one get, in integral form
$$I_{Riemann} := \int_0^{W(T)} g(x)dx = \int_0^Tg(W(t))dW(t) + \frac{1}{2} g_x(W(t))dt := I_{Ito} + \Delta$$
where $\Delta$ is the adjustment from Riemann integral to Ito, or, $I_{Ito} = I_{Riemann} - \Delta$.

So now the question is, where is the $\Delta$ from?

Let's simplify it more by taking $g(x) = x$, then $$I_{ito} = \int_0^T W(t)dW(t) = I_{Riemann} - \Delta = \int_0^{W(T)} x dx - \frac{1}{2}T = \frac{1}{2} W^2(T) - \frac{1}{2} T$$
, how can we see it intuitively that $\Delta = \frac{1}{2}T$?

Let $t\in [0,T]$ devided to $n^2$ steps, correspondingly, $x\in [0,W(T)]$;

each $n$ steps we call it a *march*, in the $k$th march, $x$ moves from $[W(T/n*k)$ to $W(T/n*(k+1))]$;

in each march, there's *one* step that finished this move, while the rest $n-1$ steps are just oscillation;

we further assume there are $(n-1)/2$ times of oscillation, each oscillation contains 2 steps, one step moving out, and one moves back;

each step moves $s$, then $s\sim N(0,\sqrt{T}/n)$.

Now, due to the definition of Ito's integral (that is similar to a Riemann sum, for each time interval $[t_1, t_2]$, take $W(t_1)*(t_2-t_1)$ as the contribution) the oscillation caused a loss:

[image]

The loss of one osccilation is $s^2$, $$E[s^2] = Var(s) = T/n^2$$

So the total loss is $$\Delta = \lim_{n\mapsto \infty} n\cdot \frac{n-1}{2} E[s^2] = \frac{1}{2}T$$, voila.

So, my intuitive understanding is, Ito integral is in time domain ($t$), while the normal Riemann integral is in the random variable value's domain ($x$ or $W(t)$), the Brownian motion has so many oscillation that the loss could not be ignored, the adjustment is the $\frac{1}{2}f_{xx}dt$ in Ito's formula.

Answer (score 2):

The first equation you've written, namely $$ dX_t = \sigma X_t dW_t \tag{1}$$ is simply a convenient, yet informal, way to denote the corresponding integral equation, it has no proper understanding apart from that. Without getting into *strong* versus *weak* solutions (which have to do with what probability spaces the processes are defined on), we say that $X_t$ solves $(1)$, with initial condition $x\in \mathbb{R}$, if it satisfies $$X_t = x + \int_0^t \sigma X_sdW_s \tag{2}$$ for all $t \geq 0,$ **almost surely**.
That is, solutions to the differential equation are only taken to hold on a set of probability one, so the situation you're describing is a moot point. Moreover, it is improper to think about $dX_t(\omega)$ being a path-wise slope, it is simply a notational shorthand.

Comment: This is helpful technically, but it does not really answer my main concern (I've reformulated it somewhat at the end of the original question). Even with this integral notation, I cannot see why $X$ moves to zero exponentially fast, regardless of how $W$ behaves.

Comment: @programmer2134 this seems to be a very different question then before the edit, or at least I'm reading it very differently, I'll try to update my answer later today.

Comment: This was really the "intention" behind my question

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with Geometric Brownian Motions, one should consider the main fact underlying Ito's algebra, that is, the fact that the Brownian motion ($W(t)$) accumulates quadratic variation at rate one per unit of time. Informally:

$$
dW_t dW_t = dt.
$$

This means that, when computing the differential $df(t, x)$, where $x=W(t)$, the Taylor expansion of such function returns a non zero second order differential associated with the pure second derivative w.r.t. $W(t)$, that is:

$$
df(t, W(t)) = f_t dt + f_{x}dx +\frac{1}{2}f_{xx}dt 
= -\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2X_tdt + \sigma X_tdW(t) + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2X_tdt,
$$

where $x=W(t)$ and the term $\frac{1}{2}f_{xx}dt = \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2X_tdt$ is the term that is due to the quadratic variation of the Brownian motion $W(t)$.

Going back to the Geometric Brownian Motion

$$
X_t=X_0e^{\sigma W(t)-\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2t},
$$

is now clear how the term $-\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2X_tdt$ compensates the quadratic variation of $W(t)$, so that the the GBM can be driftless, that is, with its differential being a martingale.