# quadratic variation of the solution to the martingale problem

Tags: markov-chains, martingales, quadratic-variation

Solution to the martingale problem for continuous-time Markov process $(X_t)$ with generator $\mathcal{L}$ is

$$M_t=f(X_t)-f(X_0)-\int_0^t\mathcal{L}f(X_s)ds,$$

given any $f$.

What I want to show is that the quadratic variation of $M_t$ is

$$\langle M\rangle_t = \int_0^t\{\mathcal{L}(f^2)-2f\mathcal{L}f\}(X_s)ds,$$

which is equivalent to showing that

$$ N_t =2\int_0^tf(X_s)\mathcal{L}f(X_s)ds - 2f(X_t)\int_0^t\mathcal{L}f(X_s)ds + \left(\int_0^t\mathcal{L}f(X_s)ds \right)^2 $$

is a martingale.

Any ideas or comments are appreciated!! Thank you.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208729/intuitive-explanation-of-doleans-exponential-of-brownian-motion/2953840#2953840 does this address your question?

Comment: I don’t see any connections to my question, though...

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1575365/36150)...

Comment: Thank you very much!!